# Mac OS Catalina not Downloading

Tags: macos, catalina, upgrade

I have re installed my mac to fresh El Capitan on my MacBook Pro. Now at the app store it is showing the Catalina version Updates but when I click on Download nothing is happening. I have previously used it but since after the fresh installation download is not working. How can I fix it? After clicking the download button, the download button fades like this but nothing is happening. Internet is working properly as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to install it by first upgrading it to Mojave then able to download and install the Catalina.

Answer (score -1):

From [Apple](https://www.apple.com/macos/how-to-upgrade/):

> **Upgrading from macOS Mojave?**
>
> Go to Software Update in System Preferences to find the macOS Catalina upgrade. Click Upgrade Now and follow the onscreen instructions to begin your upgrade. If you don’t have broadband access, you can upgrade your Mac at any Apple Store.
>
> **Upgrading from an older version of macOS?**
>
> If you’re running High Sierra (10.13), Sierra (10.12), or El Capitan (10.11), upgrade to macOS Catalina from the App Store. If you’re running Lion (10.7) or Mountain Lion (10.8), you will need to upgrade to El Capitan (10.11) first. If you don’t have broadband access, you can upgrade your Mac at any Apple Store.

Comment: OP is already on El Capitan.